# Program ignores the first letter of input

Tags: c++

I've seen other questions about this problem but I can't seem to incorporate those in my problem right here.

My Code

```
cout << "Get User's input\n";
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter the author's name: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin,a[i].name); // Ariel the Mermaid
    cout << endl;

        for (int count = 0; count < size; count++)
        {
            cout << "Enter Title " << count + 1 << "  : ";
            cin.ignore();
            getline(cin,a[i].books[count].title); // Intro to Me
            if (a[i].books[count].title == "NONE")
                break;
            cout << "Enter Price " << count + 1 << "  : $";
            cin >> a[i].books[count].price; // 49.99
        }
    cout << endl;
}
```

When I have inputted "Ariel the Mermaid", it gives me "riel the Mermaid" when I cout it. Also the "Intro to Me" gives "ntro to Me".

What's the problem with this code?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore

Comment: You are doing a cin.ignore(), which skips a character.

Comment: But I needed that so that it won't skip when I inputted my price.

Comment: @CrisToby Can you accept another workaround or re-write of your code? I think you can get the same result with much less and unneed code.

Comment: Mixing `cin >> ...` and `getline (cin,...)` gets messy. If you are going to `ignore`, do it after `cin >> a[i].books[count].price;` to gobble up the EOL.

Comment: @user4581301 THANK YOU SIR/MAM!! UR solution works!!

Comment: It only sort-of works. What if the user types in "13.95 I tot I taw a puddy tat!"? 13.95 goes into price, the space gets ignored, and the name of your next book is "I tot I taw a puddy tat!". Like I said, it gets messy. What you want is `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n')` Ignore everything to the end of the line. You will probably have to add `#include <limits>` to your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are skipping the first character with `cin.ignore()`.

A good use of `cin.ignore()` is when you have `cin >>` before a `getline()`

for example:

```
cout << "Digit you age" << endl;
cin >> age;
cout << "Digit your full Name" << endl;
cin.ignore();
getline(cin,name);
```

This happens because when the compiler reachs the `cin` will make a stop to read from the keyboard until you pressed the enter key to finish,  then the `getline()` will capture  the last character wich is a "\n". So you have to `cin.ignore()` to ignore that last character.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to [`cin.ignore()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) is ignoring one character. This method ignores a count of `n` characters provided as an argument. The default `n` is `1`.

You should delete the line with `cin.ignore ()`.

Comment: Right. And what should OP do about it?